# Reward function for intraday trading

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am working to build an deep reinforcement learning agent which can place orders (i.e. limit buy and limit sell orders). The actions are `{"Buy": 0 , "Do Nothing": 1, "Sell": 2}`.

[image]

Suppose that all the features are well suited for this task. I wanted to use just the standard "Profit & Loss" as a reward, but I hardly thought to get something similar to the above image. The standard P&L will simply place the pair (limit buy order, limit sell order) on every up movement. I don't want that because very often it won't cover the commission and it is not a good indicator to trade manually. I would be interested that the agent can maximize the profit and give me a minimum profit of $100 on every pair (limit buy order, limit sell order). On the picture, I would be interested in something similar to the above picture.

Is there a reward function that could allow me to get such a result? If so, what is it?

**UPDATE**

Is the following utility function can work with the purpose of that question?

$$
U(x) = \max(\$100, x)
$$

That seems correct, but I don't know how the agent will be penalized if it covers a wrong transaction, i.e. the pair (limit buy order, limit sell order) creates a loss of money.

Comment: Why not just give a reward of \$0 for any profit below \$100, otherwise linear? If you use gross profit less commission as the reward, the agent will implicitly have to account for transaction cost. Also, this is very nearly the toy stock trading problem outlined in Maxim Lapan's Deep RL book; might be worthwhile to take a look at it.

Comment: @Sycorax I updated the question